# Is there a way to check for a char in all elements of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array that has a couple hundred elements and need to find the ones that have a specific letter in the 2nd character in the element. Is there an easier way of doing this than a monster nested if?

Comment: Assuming element is a `String`, Loop over the elements while checking `element.charAt(1)`. If that doesnt help, provide more info in the question with examples.

Comment: have you tried anything before posting it here ?

Comment: I am trying to find if the second printed in each array is 'A'. This is what I have so far:

Comment: char aChar = opponentCard.charAt(1);
     System.out.println(aChar);
   if (aChar=='A'){
      element.charAt(1);
      }

Comment: What about regex match?

Comment: Have you heard of a **loop**? If not, go back and read your Java material, e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials - The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: See also https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you for array of Strings

```
String[] s = {"mnmmm","sdcsdc"};
       for(String h:s){
           if(h.charAt(1)=='n')
               System.out.println(h); // prints the first mnmmm
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure, you have tried yourself before posting your self..even then you cant do , then feel free to ask in stack overflow...

```
 String[] string={"string1","string2","string3","etc..."} //array that has a couple hundred elements
char thatChar='A' //specific letter in the 2nd character in the element
for(String var:string)
   if(var.charAt(1)==thatChar)
     //work here...
```

you can learn `[foreach loop`][1](http://www.javatpoint.com/for-each-loophttp://) 
and String operation: `[charAt(index)][2]`

make sure to accept this answer if it helps and if not please comment before down grade it.